# Angular inline-editing and deleting withinin *ngFor with button click

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

This is my DOM element. Data is being fetched from backend and I am using *ngFor to display data. What I want it on click of that edit button I want the respective row's text to have an `input` tag and the edit button to change to save button. And on clicking save button the input should disappear.

Below are the html code and image of my DOM element. Right now on the click of edit button I am just toggling `editable` to `true` or `false` but it's not working either.

```html
<span *ngFor="let body of myLinkBody;let last=last" class="myLinkBody" [class.myLinkBodyLast]="last">
  <a [href]="domainURL+body.href" contenteditable="editable">{{body.value}}</a>
  <div id="editLinkButton"><a (click)="edit($event,body)"></a>  </div>
  <div id="deleteLinkButton"><a></a></div>
</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a new property to each object in myLinkBody array to maintain the current state whether its being edited or not.

```
myLinkBody.map(body => { body.currentState="edit"; return body});
```

and use an extra tag input field use `[(ngModel)]`.Use `[hidden]` on both achor tag and input tag ,show and hide them based on current state.

```
<span *ngFor="let body of myLinkBody;let last=last;let i=index" class="myLinkBody" [class.myLinkBodyLast]="last">
  <a [href]="domainURL+body.href" [hidden]="body.currentState=='save'">{{body.value}}</a>
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myLinkBody[i].name" [hidden]="body.currentState=='save'"/> 
  <button (click)="edit($event,body,index)">{{body.currentState}}</button>
  <div id="deleteLinkButton"></div>
</span>
```

In edit function

```
edit(event,body,index){
   if(body.state == 'save')
       this.myLinkBody[index].state='edit'; 
    else
      this.myLinkBody[index].state='save';
    .....your code here
}
```

Example stackblitz :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hrmfv

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a basic snippet, that will display sample data as list using *ngFor, where the fields can be edited by clicking the edit button.

Check out the snippet here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmvkat

Live URL : https://angular-rmvkat.stackblitz.io/